# MongoError : pool is draining new operations prohibited

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Hi I am getting error when i run the following code :

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/odpLogs"
MongoClient.connect(url,function(err , db){
           if(err) throw err ;
           dao = db.db("odpLogs");
        dao.listCollections({},{nameOnly : true}).toArray(function(err,collectionNames){
            if(err) throw err ;
            collectionNames.forEach( collection => {
                if(collection.name.includes('.logs')){
                    var newvalues   = { $set: { logType: "api" , app : collection.name.split('.')[0]  } };
                    var renameKey = {$rename : {"method" : "operation"}} ;
                    dao.collection(collection.name).updateMany({},newvalues, function(err ,res ){
                        if(err) throw err ;
                        console.log(res);
                    }) ;
                    dao.collection(collection.name).updateMany({},renameKey, function(err ,res ){
                        if(err) throw err ;
                        console.log(res);
                    }) ;
                }
            });
        });
           db.close();

});
```

I am trying to rename key "method" to "operation", add new key logType and app for all document in collection which ends with .logs.

I get following error :

```
   throw err;
      ^

MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited
    at Pool.write (/home/meghana/Documents/Migration/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:845:8)
    at _command (/home/meghana/Documents/Migration/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:128:10)
```

Comment: I got this error when disconnecting my mongo instance before all the async code had finished.

Answer (score 2):

foreach does not wait for each db call to complete. It kicks them all off and you end up using your pool.

Try using a **for loop**:

```
for (const item of feed.items) {...}
```

If you use awaits in the for loop it will actually wait for each to complete and not drain the pool.

Answer (score 1):

```js
dao.listCollections({},{nameOnly : true}).toArray(function(err,collectionNames) {
 // your code goes here.
 // It contains other asynchronous functions as well (`updateMany`).
})
db.close()
```

`listCollections().toArray()` has an asynchronous code. In the callback function, you perform your operations you want to accomplish, but you simply cannot, because you are closing your connection EARLIER (even though it's at the bottom of the file).
Try to move the `db.close()` INSIDE the callback function or close the connection in another way.

Please note you're using `updateMany`, which is another async bit. Please read about `Promise`, `Promise.all`, and `promisify` from `util` package in node. It might come in handy.