# Jest & Node: MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I have a node.JS backend application, and I've been migrating my test runner from Mocha to Jest. I have about ~ 200 tests in total. However, after refactoring all the tests to be Jest compatible, I now get the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited

      at Pool.Object.<anonymous>.Pool.write (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:846:8)
      at _command (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:120:10)
      at command (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/command.js:28:5)
      at writeCommand (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/write_command.js:47:3)
      at Object.insert (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/wireprotocol/index.js:6:5)
      at Server.Object.<anonymous>.Server.insert (node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:698:23)
      at Server.insert (node_modules/mongodb/lib/topologies/topology_base.js:301:25)
      at insertDocuments (node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/common_functions.js:259:19)
      at InsertOneOperation.execute (node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/insert_one.js:26:5)
      at executeOperation (node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:77:17)
      at Collection.Object.<anonymous>.Collection.insertOne (node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:517:10)
      at NativeCollection.<computed> [as insertOne] (node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:180:28)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Model.$__handleSave (node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:275:33)
      at model.Object.<anonymous>.Model.$__save (node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:349:8)
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:278:20
      at node_modules/kareem/index.js:77:15
```

This error occurs about 1/3 of the time, and occurs on any test suite file. It is very unpredictable.

I am using node 14.10.1 along with these packages and versions:

- `"ts-jest": "^26.4.4"`
- `"jest": "^26.6.3"`
- `"mongodb-memory-server": "^5.2.0"`
- `"mongoose": "^5.10.11"`

Additionally, here are the related Jest setup / teardown files:

#### `database_helper.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

async function connect() {
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 0) {
    return;
  }

  await mongoose.connect(global['__DB_URL__'], {
    autoReconnect: true,
    poolSize: 10,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
  });
}

async function truncate() {
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
    return;
  }

  const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;

  const promises = Object.keys(collections).map(col => {
    return mongoose.connection.collection(col).deleteMany({});
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);
}

async function disconnect() {
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) {
    return;
  }

  await mongoose.disconnect();
}

module.exports = {
  connect,
  truncate,
  disconnect,
};
```

#### `environment.js`

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');
const { dbServer } = require('./memory_db_server');

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    this.global.__DB_URL__ = await dbServer.getConnectionString();
  }

  async teardown() {
    await super.teardown();
  }

  runScript(script) {
    return super.runScript(script);
  }
}

module.exports = CustomEnvironment;
```

#### `memory_db_server.js`

```js
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server');

class MemoryDatabaseServer {
  constructor() {
    this.mongod = new MongoMemoryServer({
      binary: {
        version: '4.0.3',
      },
      autoStart: false,
      instance: {
        storageEngine: 'wiredTiger',
      },
    });
  }

  start() {
    return this.mongod.start();
  }

  stop() {
    return this.mongod.stop();
  }

  getConnectionString() {
    return this.mongod.getConnectionString();
  }
}

module.exports = { dbServer: new MemoryDatabaseServer() };
```

#### `setup.js`

```js
const { dbServer } = require('./memory_db_server');

module.exports = async () => await dbServer.start();
```

#### `teardown.js`

```js
const { dbServer } = require('./memory_db_server');

module.exports = async () => await dbServer.stop();
```

#### `setupAfterEnv.js`

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const dbHelper = require('./database_helper');

beforeAll(dbHelper.connect);

beforeEach(dbHelper.truncate);

afterAll(dbHelper.disconnect);
```

I am also using the `--runInBand` Jest option to run the tests sequentially.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that all the test suites run perfectly individually; this problem only occurs when I run all of them.

---

I have come across several related posts, but no solutions have worked so far:

- [MongoError : pool is draining new operations prohibited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60852187/mongoerror-pool-is-draining-new-operations-prohibited) (I'm not using `.forEach(async ...)`
- [MongoError: pool is draining, new operations prohibited when using MongoMemoryServer in integration test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61152884/mongoerror-pool-is-draining-new-operations-prohibited-when-using-mongomemoryse) (I am using `--runInBand` and setting my pool size to 10)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: if you command this line `afterAll(dbHelper.disconnect);` and don't disconnet, what happens?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi same error :/